# How to get Kafka messages based on timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am working on a application in which I am using kafka and tech is scala. My kafka consumer code is as follows:

```
val props = new Properties()
        props.put("group.id", "test")
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
        props.put("group.id", "consumer-group")
    val consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, String] = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
    consumer.subscribe(util.Collections.singletonList(topic))
    val record = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500)).asScala.toList
```

It gives me all the records but the thing is I already have data in kafka consumer  which may lead to duplicate data means data with same key can already be there in topic. Is there is any way by which I can retrieve data from a particular time. Means before polling if I can calculate current time and retrieve only those records which came after that time. Any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to consume from any given timestamp is to

1. Lookup [`offsetsForTimes`](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#offsetsForTimes-java.util.Map-)
2. `seek` to and `commitSync` that result
3. Begin polling

**But**, you need to be conscious that the data stream is continuous and there may again be repeated keys later.

---

If you have the same key in data, that you would like to only see the latest of, then you'd be better off using a KTable

Comment: Apologies, didn't want to copy your answer... just took some time to actually write and test my piece of code.

Comment: @mike It's fine. I've written the code before using all Futures classes, so it's much messier than yours

Answer (score 2):

You can use the offsetsForTimes [method](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#offsetsForTimes-java.util.Map-) in the KafkaConsumer API.

### Code

```scala
import java.time.Duration
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition
import collection.JavaConverters._

object OffsetsForTime extends App {

  implicit def toJavaOffsetQuery(offsetQuery: Map[TopicPartition, scala.Long]): java.util.Map[TopicPartition, java.lang.Long] =
    offsetQuery
      .map { case (tp, time) => tp -> new java.lang.Long(time) }
      .asJava

  val topic = "myInTopic"
  val timestamp: Long = 1595971151000L

  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("group.id", "group-id1337")
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
  val consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, String] = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)

  val topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, 0)
  consumer.assign(java.util.Collections.singletonList(topicPartition))
  // dummy poll before calling seek
  consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500))

  // get next available offset after given timestamp
  val (_, offsetAndTimestamp) = consumer.offsetsForTimes(Map(topicPartition -> timestamp)).asScala.head
  // seek to offset
  consumer.seek(topicPartition, offsetAndTimestamp.offset())

  // poll data
  val record = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500)).asScala.toList

  for (data <- record) {
    println(s"Timestamp: ${data.timestamp()}, Key: ${data.key()}, Value: ${data.value()}")
  }

}
```

### Test

```sh
./kafka/current/bin/kafconsole-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic myInTopic --from-beginning --property print.value=true --property print.timestamp=true
CreateTime:1595971142560    1_old
CreateTime:1595971147697    2_old
CreateTime:1595971150136    3_old
CreateTime:1595971192649    1_new
CreateTime:1595971194489    2_new
CreateTime:1595971196416    3_new
```

Selecting the timestamp to a time between `3_old` and `1_new` to only consume the "new" messages.

### Output

```sh
Timestamp: 1595971192649, Key: null, Value: 1_new
Timestamp: 1595971194489, Key: null, Value: 2_new
Timestamp: 1595971196416, Key: null, Value: 3_new
```