# Fetch all the messages from kafka with start and end time

Tags: apache-kafka

could you please help me here?
I am having Kafka cluster in environment and I need to create a job that read the messages from all partitions of Kafka topic based on start and end time. So, It is like I want to read all the messages from Kafka topic from 00:00:09:14:09:2020(SEC-MINUTES-HOURS-DAY-MONTH-YEAR) to  00:00:10:14:09:2020 (1 hours duration). Python or Java any of the these two languages will be fine for the solution or even linux command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Kafka messages based on timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140301/how-to-get-kafka-messages-based-on-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

Kafka provides a time index that contains a mapping between a relative message offset (within the segment) and the corresponding message time (LogAppendTime or CreateTime depending on log.message.timestamp.type - broker/topic configuration).

Kafka consumer API provides the method `offsetsForTimes` to find the offset in each partition for a given timestamp.

Once you have the starting offset, use the method `seek` to set the starting offset and start polling until the offset of the consumed message is greater than the end offset (obtained in the same way as above) of the range. When the end of the range is reached, do a `seekToEnd`

Comment: Greatly appreciated if you provide some sample snippets much helpful for newbies
thanks