# In Kafka, how to find the offsets for all partitions between given start and end date (or say timestamp) and replay the msgs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to find all offsets between given start and end date and later replay the msg as for this time period msgs were lost.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140301/how-to-get-kafka-messages-based-on-timestamp

Comment: You can use kafkacat utility to get all messages between timestamps or offset. See more details here:
https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat or
https://docs.confluent.io/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html#consumer-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset offsets for consumer group by using kafka-consumer-groups tool - https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.1/kafka-managing/topics/kafka-manage-cli-cgroups.html (this is from cloudera, but included in any kafka distribution from v0.11)

You could also run the following:
`./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list <hostname>:<port> --time <epoch> --topic <topic>` and get offset by time.
Refer to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-GetOffsetShell

Comment: I dont want to reset, what I want is to find the offsets for all partitions between given start and end date (or say timestamp) and replay the msgs. as due to some reason, consumer didnt consume the msgs so need to replay them.

Comment: Resetting will result in the consumer consuming these messages again, so there's no need to replay. Alternatively, you could create a new consumer group which will do the exact same processing your current consumer group is doing, and set it to start from the timestamp you need (though I'm not aware of any option that would allow you to stop consumption once you reached the last offset that was not consumed)

Comment: I've updated my answer anyway, I believe this is what you look for

Comment: if we reset then, will it consume msgs between that start date to end date only..? for eg start date is 1 oct and end date is 15 oct msgs were lost (i need to replay them) , and after then from 16 oct, consumer was consuming without any issue. will from this period only reset work?

Comment: If you reset a consumer group, it will continue to consume (will not skip the messages since Oct 16th). But in any case, you will face the same problem if you consume with a different consumer group, or if you replay the data from the topic to itself. So you need to address this in your code - have a check that you stop when you reach the last offset you need.