# How to insert & read records in sequence?

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, plsql, triggers

Given `unprocessed_TableA` schema:

```
 PK(col_1, col_2, col_3), col_4, col_5
 col_1 VARCHAR2(2)
 col_2 VARCHAR(16)
 col_3 VARCHAR(3)
 col_4 NUMBER
 col_5 NUMBER
```

Above schema can accomodate extra column to maintain sequencing

---

Backend service receives new record set(more than one record) from kafka to store in database. So, maintaining the sequence in important

1. How to `INSERT` new records in sequence in table `unprocessed_TableA` ? so that `SELECT` can read the records from `unprocessed_TableA` in a range of sequence(1-n)

---

Given `processing_TableA` schema:

```
 PK(col_1, col_2, col_3), col_4, col_5
 col_1 VARCHAR2(2)
 col_2 VARCHAR(16)
 col_3 VARCHAR(3)
 col_4 NUMBER
 col_5 NUMBER
```

2. Upon `SELECT` query of records(in sequence) from `unprocessed_TableA`, trigger `INSERT` query on those same records in sequence to table  `processing_TableA`. How to write a trigger on `SELECT` query?

Comment: 1) Oracle does not maintain the records "in order" internally. You must have a column in the data that you can sort by using an `order by` clause in your select query. For example, you might use a timestamp column with a default value of `systimestamp` to record the time of the insert. 2) You cannot create a trigger on a `select`; only on `insert`, `update`, or `delete`: things that *change* the data in some way.

Comment: @pmdba Considering timestamp column, It we INSERT multiple rows, then more than one row can have same timestamp

Comment: Ideally your message queue has assigned some sort of message id or other identifier which can be used to order your data. That should be included in your table, if possible. Also, if your application is using a connection pool to submit inserts in parallel, or is using a multi-node database (Oracle RAC) then you'll need to have some property to order by in the data itself; Oracle will have no way to know for sure in which order data was received by the service, and you should *never* leave this kind of thing to implicit sorting by order of insert.

Comment: @pmdba sequencing in Kafka is within partition(called offset). That may not help. Does referenced answer(using AUTO_INCREMENT) relevant to my requirement?

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` is essentially a system-defined sequence assigned to a primary key column. It will have the same potential issues as using any other sequence.: values will be unique, but not necessarily in order. Modern methods of scaling - connection pools,  clustering, etc. - will make it impossible for the database to know in which order specific records were received by an external service. The only way to be sure a sequence will work would be to limit yourself to a single database connection on a singe-instance database: essentially to serialize everything and make it unscalable.

Comment: @pmdba assuming we use single database connection with single DB instance, what would be the max value of `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, because we are storing real time streaming data coming from Kafka to database

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571

Comment: Note that the "answer" pointed to as a duplicate is **not correct** for this use case, but because the question is closed I can't add a new answer. For Kafka messages, you need to capture the topic name, topic partition and offset in your data collection. That is the only way to identify a specific message or order results. Use of a sequence (auto increment or otherwise) is **NOT** a consistent, scalable, reliable solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65935155/identify-and-find-specific-message-in-kafka-topic

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a trigger which would insert a sequence number into the table:

```
create sequence seq;

create or replace trigger trg_bi_ta
  before insert on unprocessed_TableA 
  for each row
begin
  :new.col_4 := seq.nextval;
end;
/
```

Then you'd

```
select * from unprocessed_TableA order by col_4;
```

and get rows in the same order as they were inserted.

---

Your 2nd requirement doesn't make sense. `select` can't fire any triggers, so - if you want to *copy* data from one table to another, you'd do it manually:

```
insert into processing_TableA (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
from unprocessed_TableA;
```

If you planned to *skip* `order by` clause, don't do that. It is the only way you'll get rows in desired order.

Comment: `col_4` is an existing column `:new.col_4`. I didn;t get this syntax

Comment: I presumed that COL_4 is the one that is supposed to contain sequence number. In trigger, we reference it using the :NEW pseudorecord identifier. Basically, it says: put the next sequence number into COL_4 column.

Comment: A sequence would only work if you are using a single instance database. If your target environment includes multiple nodes (i.e. Oracle RAC), then you cannot use a sequence for this purpose, as each node will cache a separate set of sequence values and there is no guarantee that returned values will be in numeric order. A sequence only ever guarantees that the returned value will be *unique*.

Comment: Further note: if using multiple connections form the app (like a connection pool) to insert the data, a sequence will only identify the order in which records are received *by the database*. There's no guarantee that records will be inserted by the database in the same order they were received by the app if they are spread over multiple connections for scaling purposes.