# Consume Kafka topic in specific time range

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to consume data in topic between specific time range using java. Do you have any approach to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Note, that Kafka topics are mainly meant to contain a stream of data (which is continuous and unbound), so there is no out of the box way to solve your issue.

However, you can make use of the KafkaConsumer method `offsetsForTimes` as e.g. described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140301/how-to-get-kafka-messages-based-on-timestamp/63143065#63143065) to convert the timestamps (beginning and end) into the equivalent offsets.

Having those offsets you can make your consumer start reding from the beginning offsets and make it stop when it reached the end offset.

Comment: Mike, thanks for you fast answer. I got it. Actually I was thinking like you. So, I need to get a snapshot of large JSON data in time range. Real time is not important. Time range changes most time. Do you have any idea to do that simplify?

Comment: Glad it helped. Not sure if I understood you correctly, but why not put the JSON string into a column in a simple database, have the time of that json in another column and then query all relevant json string based on a time range?