# Delayed packet consumptions in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

is it possible to pick the packets by consumers after defined time in the packet by kafka consumer or how can we achieve this in kafka?

Found related question, but it didn't help. As I see: Kafka is based on sequential reads from file system and can be used only to read topics straightforward keeping message ordering. Am I right?

same is possible with rabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you would need to consume the data, deserialize it and inspect the time field. Then append to some priority queue data structure and start a background timer thread to check if events from this queue should further be processed, and not block the Kafka consumer.

The only downside to this approach is that you then need to worry about processing and committing "shorter time" events that are read by the consumer while waiting for previously consumed "longer time". Otherwise, a restart of your client will drop all events from an in memory queue and start consuming after the last committed record.

You might be able to workaround this using a persistent "outbox pattern" database table, or otherwise tracking offsets and processed records manually, and seeking past any duplicates

Comment: i want consumer to pick that packet after inspecting time field.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "packet". You'll have full access to the `ConsumerRecord` on each poll. Are you looking for [`offsetsForTime` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140301/how-to-get-kafka-messages-based-on-timestamp)? That has nothing to do with "delaying" consumption